# How to show current value in dropdownlist while editing the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I have a dropdown list on my page. When I try to edit some row on it, the value in the dropdown list is set to it's default value.

I want dropdownlist to show the current value of the row which is being edited.

Comment: are you talking about editable dropdown list?

Comment: No. I have a row which consists edit option . When i click on edit a dropdown list appears from where i have to select a value..So when i click on edit it is always showing default value rather than the the current value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the dropdown is in a template column... So at each postback you have to set its selected value. **Not in if(!isPostback)** in **all postbacks**.

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("dd"));
```

In place of dd.You can pass the current Text of the row.

you can use like this.

```
ddl.SelectedIndex=ddl.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("dd"));
```

in place of dd u can pass your row text. Hope you want to perform this.

If you want to show the ABC, you can try with following code

as textbox or whatever control you are using,I am assuming u have used textbox

```
Textbox t1=(Textbox)Griview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Your control ID") as TextBox
```

then

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(t1.ToString()));
```

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
      
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlBU_ID");
            e.NewValues["BU_Id"] = ddl.SelectedValue; 
        } This is the code that i have in my aspx.cs file. Can you please tell me should i replace this by yours.

Comment: What you want to do? can you be more specific. as i can see the code it is the gridview and all..

Comment: Okay..I have an accounts page. I added a command field (Edit,Update,Cancel) to the entity datasource1 and table name is Account_Master. Now if i click on edit i will be able to update that particular row. So One of the column in that row is a dropdown list and its data source is entitydatasource 2 which is comming from another table named BU_Master. Now the problem is when i click on edit the dropdownlist is showing the default value(eg: if the current value of row is ABC when i click on Edit its showing XYZ This is happening for al rows.I dont want this to happen

Comment: i have 5 records in the table (ABC,DEf,GHI,JKL,XYZ)..Now in the dropdownlist i am able to see all these.But when i edit any one of the record in the web page i.e if i edit GHI or DEF or JKl or XYZ it is not showing that particular value rather it is showing ABC. (EX:If i edit DEF it shoud show DEF value in dropdown list. If i edit JKL it should show JKL)But whatever i EDIT its showing ABC

Comment: You can try above code.. the logic is .. just take the text of textbox( you must have used the textbox for editting ) then pass that text in dropdownlist. You can see the above code.